# Can't get JSON to work to pass data between pages

Tags: javascript, json

I have the following html code which is just an item name from a view cart page. I want to be able to transfer this data (amongst others once i get the basic idea down) to a separate html page that'll automatically generate a list of multiple items, with multiple prices and output a total price.

```
<div class="product-name-options"> 
            <!--START: itemnamelink--><a id="itemName" href="product.asp?itemid=[ITEM_CATALOGID]">[ITEM_NAME]</a><!--END: itemnamelink--> 

<button type="button" onclick="window.location='Quote_ep_78-1.html'" id="vc_ChkButton" class="btn"><i class="icon-basket"></i> Get Quote</button>

</div>
```

I have the following Json code on the cart page.

```
       <script>
     jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {

    var itemName = document.getElementById('itemName');

if(typeof(Storage)!=="undefined")
  {
var me = {name: itemName};
localStorage.setItem("user",JSON.stringify(me));
  }
else
  {
  // Sorry! No Web Storage support..
  }


});


    </script>
```

This is the quote page.

```
<script>

jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {

console.log(localStorage.getItem("user"));

});

     /*document.write("Quantity = " + localStorage.getItem("user") + "<br>");*/

    </script>

 <div id="add">




    </div>

 </head>

<body>


    <div id = ".myDivClass">




    </div>



   </body>
```

I can't seem to get the jSON data appear in the div that i've made furthermore at the moment i get the following in a console.log command

```
"{"name":{}}"
```

I get the above console.log which i believe is correct as it reflects the number of items in my cart but i can't get it to print anything else. This is my first ever time using JSON so i'm a bit out of my depth but i'm eager to learn how to do this and expand it so i can print out on the page multiple items

Comment: I think your itemName might be a html element rather than a string. what if you hardcode the value of itemName to e.g. 'test'?

Answer (score 0):

```
var itemName = document.getElementById('itemName');
```

itemName is a html element (in this case it is an a tag). I am not sure what kind of data you want to transfer to another page. But you can put it in an object and save it to localstorage.
If you want to put a tag's text in the localstorage, try this out.

```
var me = {name: itemName.textContent};
localStorage.setItem("user",JSON.stringify(me));
```